# Create HostEndpoint resouce using calico operator

Tags: kubernetes, calico, calicoctl

Is it possible to create resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: HostEndpoint
```

using calico operator?
I want to get rid of `calicoctl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible only with `calicoctl` to create a host endpoint resource.

As mentioned in the [document](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/host-endpoints/objects):

> For each host endpoint that you want Calico to secure, you’ll need to
> create a host endpoint object in etcd. Use the `calicoctl create`
> command to create a host endpoint resource (HostEndpoint).

There are two ways to specify the interface that a host endpoint should refer to. You can either specify the name of the interface or its expected IP address. In either case, you’ll also need to know the name given to the Calico node running on the host that owns the interface; in most cases this will be the same as the hostname of the host.

Comment: It is disappointing that I have to take care of additional binary when all of it could be done by the operator. Hope that Tigera will implement that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to autocreate `hostEndpoint`s for all the worker nodes. You could patch the `kubecontrollersconfiguration` resource directly without `calicoctl`.

```
kubectl patch kubecontrollersconfiguration default --type=merge --patch='{"spec": {"controllers": {"node": {"hostEndpoint": {"autoCreate": "Enabled"}}}}}'
```